# Unlock an account in oracle 12c database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I tried to run a spring mvc code and got a jdbc connection error: cannot open connection. I tried to connect the database in sqldeveloper but my account was locked.

So I tried using sqlplus in command prompt. Since I am having multiple db_homes, and oracle home was not set it throwed an error sqlplus is not an internal command. I have fixed it by checking the db_home path and fixed and after that I gave the command "alter user system account unlock" it altered.

Then I tried to connect the database in sql developer with the user name and password but still its locked. Is that anyother thing, I need to do to unlock the account? Please need suggestion on this. It was working earlier.

Comment: Why are you connecting as `system`? Are you sure you're connecting to the same database from Java, SQL Developer and SQL*Plus?

Comment: I am giving the same thing everywhere, in sqlplus if am giving username system and password its showing invalid username/password, logon denied but in the sql plus if i try to connect as sysdba, then the password, its connecting to the oracle 12c database

Comment: I am new to oracle,by the time of installation I have used system as username. so i kept it as it is and it worked fine till now before getting unlocked

Comment: Even I tried with other account such as SYS to unlock with the username system and password oracleadmin, its not working. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Does `select account_status, lock_date from dba_users where username = 'SYSTEM';` say it is open or locked, and if it's locked, what date does it have?

Comment: Account status is open.

Comment: OK, so if you connect from SQL Developer now does it still say that it's locked; and if it does then re-run that query and see if that also now says it's locked - what exact error you do get? If SQL Developer says it's locked and SQL*Plus still says it's open, then I can only suggest you're connecting to two different databases... If SQL*Plus also now says it's locked then your connection attempt is locking it, by giving the wrong password or not specifying `as sysdba`, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: oracle.javatools.db.DBException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28000: the account is locked..I am getting this error in SQL developer.In the sql plus command prompt, its showing invalid username,password; logon denied. If am giving show user, its showing only SYS not SYSTEM. You are right I guess, I will check whether am referring different databases and will let u know. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

**Once logged in as SYSDBA, you need to unlock the SCOTT account**

SQL> alter user scott account unlock;

SQL> grant connect, resource to scott;

Answer (score 2):

You can use below steps to account unlock

```
SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='MITO_UAT';

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------
MITO_UAT                       LOCKED

SQL> alter user MITO_UAT account unlock;

User altered.

SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='MITO_UAT';

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------
MITO_UAT                       OPEN

SQL> conn MITO_UAT/MITO_UAT
Connected.
SQL>
```